# What are the machines used in Japan for hand-drawn animation?

Tags: anime-production

In Japan, there are machines used for hand-drawn animation. Not drawing tablets but, the machines used to scan the drawings, color them, as well as do the effects. Also, the machine that brings everything together in the end. That includes character's, backgrounds, sound and effects. I believe that process is called 3D compositing.

What are the names of any of the machines used in Japan for hand-drawn animation? You don't need to know every machine, just 1 would be fine.

Comment: I would imagine they are the same as machines used for non-anime analog animation. Have you tried searching for analog cartoon production machinery?

Comment: When you do, make sure to update your question with clarification if that's not what you meant, or if you find what you were looking for, you can post your own answer with the names, descriptions and pictures. It's not bad to answer your own questions here, quite the opposite − you'll also get the reputation from the upvotes.

Comment: Ok thanks.i heard of 3d compositind from a youtube channel i saw last year . I think it was called the making Of naruto the movie.I don't know how to use links on this phone but it's a bald light skin male who says hello my name is dave witten berg and i play kakashi.The name might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have studied this kind of course. Tools for animation have many, you asked traditional animation question. There was no machine to work all-in-one. In this kind of animation, you need at least 2 machines to work. At least a computer, and a hand-drawn animation scanner (for paperwork) *or* a graphic tablet (for digital).

The production steps are:

1. First, the machine producers need a hand-drawn animation scanner for their cel-work to make it more accurately. For digital artists, they just need a graphics tablet.
2. After that, into the second machine is a computer having programs such as RETAS' all products, Celsy, western Anime Studio, Pencil 2D, TVPaint, toonboom and others. Don't forget Adobe.

   Deep into scanning, cleaning art, or drawing or (you can use a mouse and line/pen tool on your scanned work), coloring, animate, effect, background. All completed by one in this steps.

   Or to answer your "3D composition", it means into 3D Software add-on animation, the technique is for video production or 3D artists. 3D animation major work on Mac/OS.
3. During the second machine working-in-progress, the production has a third machine, that is a sound-recording machine to input sound in.
4. After complete the above steps, an animation is come out. It can take more than thousands/ten-thousands hours.